# Pronunciation of `Rng` - the non-unital Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

I chuckled the first time I heard that a `Ring` without a *multiplicative identity* (R**i**ng without the `i`) is called a `Rng` (pronounced *wrong*). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29), it's pronounced *rung*.

How is `Rng` pronounced in research/academia?

Comment: I didn't know that. Funny, indeed. :D

Comment: Basically this issue is one motivation not to speak of rngs, but rather of non-unital rings or pseudo-rings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've always heard it said "rung" since that is close to a phonetic attempt.

But really, in most serious stuff, I think it's preferred to say "in this paper, rings are not assumed to have identity."

You might also enjoy knowing that there is a similar thing done for [semirings](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), that is, a structure like a ring, but the requirement for additive inverses is omitted. Some people call them **rigs** since they are missing **n**egatives.